# Torch: How are model parameters updated?

Tags: machine-learning, lua, torch

Here is a toy model. I print the model parameters before calling `backward` exactly once, then print the model parameters again. The parameters are unchanged. If I add the line `model:updateParameters(<learning_rate>)` after calling `backward`, I see the parameters update.

But in the example code I've seen, for example https://github.com/torch/demos/blob/master/train-a-digit-classifier/train-on-mnist.lua, no one actually calls `updateParameters`. Also, it doesn't look like `optim.sgd`, `optim.adam`, or `nn.StochasticGradient` ever call `updateParameters` either. What am I missing here? How do the parameters get updated automatically? If I must call `updateParameters`, why do no examples do that?

```
require 'nn'
require 'optim'

local model = nn.Sequential()
model:add(nn.Linear(4, 1, false))
local params, grads = model:getParameters()

local criterion = nn.MSECriterion()
local inputs    = torch.randn(1, 4)
local labels    = torch.Tensor{1}

print(params)

model:zeroGradParameters()
local output = model:forward(inputs)
local loss   = criterion:forward(output, labels)
local dfdw   = criterion:backward(output, labels)
model:backward(inputs, dfdw)

-- With the line below uncommented, the parameters are updated:
-- model:updateParameters(1000)

print(params)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `backward()` is not supposed to change parameters, it merely computes the derivatives of the error function with respect to all of the parameters of the network.

In general the training is the sequence of the steps:

```
repeat
  local output = model:forward(input) --see what model predicts
  local loss = criterion:forward(output, answer) --see how wrong it is
  local loss_grad = criterion:backward(output, answer) --see where it is the most wrong
  model:backward(input,loss_grad) --see how much each particular parameter of network is responsible for error
  model:updateParameters(learningRate) --fix the parameters based on their wrongness
  model:zeroGradParameters() --network parameters are different now, so old gradients are of no use now
until is_user_satisfied()
```

`updateParameters` implements the most simple optimization algorithm here (gradient descent).
If so inclined, you may use your own function instead. In theory, you might perform explicit loops through the network storages to update their values.
In practice, you usually call `getParameters()`

```
local model_parameters,model_parameters_gradient=model:getParameters()
```

Which yields you homogeneous tensors of all the values and the gradients. These tensors are views inside the network, so changes in them affect the network.
You may not know which point in the network corresponds to which value, but most optimizers do not care about that.

The [demo](https://github.com/torch/demos/blob/master/train-a-digit-classifier/train-on-mnist.lua) of `optim.sgd` usage is as follows:

```
optim.sgd(
   function_to_return_error_and_its_gradients, 
   model_parameters,
   optimizer_special_settings)
```

The specifics are covered in demo, but here it is relevant that optimizer receives the `model_parameters` as a parameter which gives it write access to network. And it is not explicitly stated in the documentation, but in the [source code](https://github.com/torch/optim/blob/master/sgd.lua) it is seen, that the optimizer changes the values of its input tensor (also, note that it is returning the **same** tensor it received).

Comment: Really thorough, thank you. So to reiterate, `updateParameters` is used to "manually" update the parameters. And the optimization algorithms just update their reference to the flattened parameters because calling `updateParameters` would not account for the optimizations.